# array without pre-defined size

Tags: c#

I'm really really new to C# and i'm trying to write a code that calculate the average of N numbers,so the program asks the user how many numbers do u have and based on the number that user enters it builds an array. 
I don't know how to implement this into code, I mean as far as I know yet arrays must be defined with their size.
can anyone help me please?

Comment: You can use a `List<type>`, which is a collection of type `type` without a predefined size. If you want to use integers, use `List<int>`

Comment: Note that the `visual-studio` tag should only be used for questions about the Visual Studio IDE, not code you write using it.

Comment: I dont get this question. If you ask the user how many numbers he has, then you know the size of the aray.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use an array?

Comment: You can try *splitting* user input into the array: `string[] items = Console.ReadLine().Split(new char [] {',', ' ', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list, for example:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
numbers.Add(5);
```

Though if you ask the user the number of numbers, then you can just initialize the array to that length:

```
Console.Write("How many numbers do you have?: ");
int numberOfNumbers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // get user input, parse it
int[] items = new int[numberOfNumbers];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNumbers; ++i)
{
    Console.Write("Enter number: ");
    items[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Hopefully you can apply these examples to your own scenario. If you have any questions, let me know in the comments.

Note that it's safer to use [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) as that actually checks if the number is valid, but for the sake of keeping the answer short, I've used `Parse`.

Comment: Thank you for the downvote kindly stranger :) Can you advise what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: you are helping turn SO into a free code writing service.

Comment: @Selman there's a big difference between giving a beginner who has done a bit of research but can't quite bridge the gap, and someone presenting a list of requirements and hoping that somebody will write it for them. I understand this question as someone just needing a little pointer.